# Trigger url when confluence page is changed

Tags: triggers, confluence, server-side

I want to run a python script on a server (different from the confluence server) whenever some of the pages in Confluence are changed. How would I do this?

I don't want to trigger the update via Javascript (because that would mean I'd have to open the server with the script to the world), but I want to trigger the change server side.

I tried the HTML include macro, but this macro doesn't let me specify which of the confluence pages has been changed.

We use confluence 4.1.6.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to monitor a email inbox for page updates.

- Create a user as a script proxy.
- Add the user as a watcher for the pages you are interested in.
- Your script would poll the inbox of the user for any emails from your instance of Confluence.
- Extract URL of the page from the email body.
- Delete / Move the email away from inbox to mark it as complete.